# How do I access Firestore field value without knowing the name?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading data to Firestore like so:

```
 func uploadTrackedSymptomValues(symptom: String, comment: String, time: String, timestamp: Int) {
    print("Uploading symptom values.")
    let user_id = FirebaseManager.shared.user_id
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(user_id!).collection("symptom_data").document("\(symptom)_data")

    let updateData = [String(timestamp) : ["symptom" : symptom, "severity" : severity, "comment" : comment, "timestamp" : String(timestamp)]]
    docRef.setData(updateData, merge: true)
    docRef.setData(updateData, merge: true) { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err?.localizedDescription as Any)
            self.view.makeToast(err?.localizedDescription as! String)
        } else {
            print("Symptom Data Uploaded")
            self.view.makeToast("\(symptom) logged at \(time). Severity: \(self.severity). Comment: \(comment)", duration: 2.0, position: .center, title: "Success!", image: self.cellImage) { didTap in
                if didTap {
                    print("completion from tap")
                } else {
                    print("completion without tap")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On Firestore this looks like:[image]

Now I want to use each field under the timestamp, for a `UITableViewCell` But I am not sure how to access the field under the document, for example `1556998898` under `Anxiety_data` so I can access:

```
 comment = "comment";
 severity = "Mild";
 symptom = "Anxiety";
 timestamp = 1556998898;
```

To use in the UITableViewCell, With realtime database I would use `childAdded listener`. I have tried:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let index = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntryDataCell", for: indexPath) as! EntryDataCell
    cell.configureCustomCell()

    let user_id = FirebaseManager.shared.user_id
    let symptomRef = db.collection("users").document(user_id!).collection("symptom_data").document(symptomSections[index])
    symptomRef.getDocument(completion: { (document, err) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("\(document.documentID) : \(dataDescription)")
            cell.commentLabel.text = dataDescription //<- Stuck here

        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

But I am stuck as to how I would get the specific field, as I don't know the name as it is the timestamp of when it was made, rather than the whole document. If there is a better way to handle this please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT:

I am able to get the Key (Timestamp) and Values but am having trouble parsing the values:

```
 let obj = dataDescription
            for (key, value) in obj! {
                print("Property: \"\(key as String)\"") //<- prints Timestamp
                print("Value: \"\(value)\"") // <- prints the comment,severity,symptom,timestamp fields I need.
            }
```

If I try to do `cell.titleLabel.text = value["comment"]` I get `Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`

I thought about using a struct:

```
   struct FieldValues: Codable {
let comment: String
let severity: String
let symptom: String
let timestamp: Int
 }
```

But am unsure on how to use it with the `value`. I feel I am in a bit over my head for this last part.

Comment: You can iterate the names of the fields in the document.  `document.data()` just returns an NSDictionary that you can work with normally. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#data

Comment: I'm very close, I can get the `key, value` from the `document.data()` I expected to be able to do `value["comment"]` but that raises an error, could you point me into the right direction for how to get thoes values? I am updating the question with more details

Comment: You'll need a nested loop for the nested fields. `for (key2, value2) in value! {`